# Is this the structure of verb + object + adverbial phrase?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis

In ‘point new Gryffindors in the right direction ‘, is this the structure of verb + indirect object + direct object, or verb + object + adverbial phrase? As a Korean, I’m easier to accept the former according to my language habit. So I’m confused which one is right?

> Nearly Headless Nick was always happy to **point new Gryffindors in the right direction**, but Peeves the Poltergeist was worth two locked doors and a trick staircase if you met him when you were late for class. (from Harry Potter book 1)

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Why do you think *"in the right direction"* might be a "direct object"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the second:

> point [VERB] new Gryffindors [OBJECT] in the right direction
>   [ADVERBIAL]

Comment: This is very similar to OP's [catch off-guard question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91077) yesterday: both phrases conclude with a modifying phrase **required by the idiom**. I am tempted to call this one an "adverbial complement", and the other an "adjectival complement".

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky. It could also be subject - verb phrase - direct object - prepositional object (cf. Biber et al. 1999: 150-1). That is, 'point' is a distransitive verb thas has distransitive prepositional uses, 'in the right direction'. Here is an example from Biber et al. (1999: 151):

He only **told** his name **to** an Italian painter named Carlino.

Comment: I don't much care for "prepositional object" or "distransitive" here. The obligatory third argument of *point* might be realized by some other construction than a prepositional phrase--*north*, for instance--and a directional word or phrase isn't an "object" of the verb in the same way that an indirect object (like that in your example from Biber) is. I think it would make more sense to call it an *argument* or *complement* and characterize it as *adverbial* or *directional* or something of that sort.