# Offer me (something) or offer (something) for me?

Tags: verbs, formality, syntactic-analysis

I have an issue with the usage of the word *offer*. This particular sentence below is giving me a headache.

> I am positive that these two subjects can offer me the best opportunities, as I take interest in both the core and the related areas.

Is that correct? And if so, is this alternative correct too?

Should *for* be replaced with *to*? (keep in mind it is supposed to be formal)

> I am positive that these two subjects can offer the best opportunities for me, as I take interest in both the core and the related areas.

Comment: Neither of the sentences make sense.  To me, it is not clear what "as I take..." means or how it relates to the initial clause.  Also, what do you mean by subjects?

Comment: Certainly, I am seeing the sentence out of context, but still...  You might considering writing two sentences.

Comment: First of all, you wouldn't put a comma before "as."  You are using it as a subordinating conjunction.  The comma creates a confusion about what you mean.  The other thing that creates confusion is semantics.  It's hard to imagine how these subjects can offer you opportunities while you take interest in their core and related areas, for how how can you cultivate opportunity from something you are just now taking interest in and haven't yet learned?

Comment: Second, the first construction is entirely proper.  It's using the ditransitive property of the verb.  It's just like saying, "She made me cookies."  In this example, the indirect object "me" is properly put immediately after the verb and before the direct object "cookies."  Your construction is exactly the same.  It puts the indirect object "me" properly before the direct object "the best opportunities."  Frankly, I don't like your second construction, not because it's wrong but because it feels stilted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this an objective complement or adjective phrase?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/is-this-an-objective-complement-or-adjective-phrase)

Answer (score 1):

*Offer* takes *to* for its indirect object, so

> ... offer the best opportunities to me.

is the normal formal form.

Many ditransitive verbs allow the indirect object to precede the direct object without a preposition, so

> ... offer me the best opportunities.

is exactly equivalent to the above, but perhaps a little less formal.

*Offer X for (person) Y* is not normal, but *opportunity for* is; so in this case, *for* is possible not because of the "offer" but because of "opportunity, and it parses as

> ... offer [the best opportunities for me].

Answer (score 0):

Both of those sentences are acceptable, in my opinion neither is more formal than the other.  The difference between them is the first is an indirect object and the second is a direct object followed by an adverbial/prepositional phrase.